Swift UIKit ordering and positioning with constraints inside a custom table cell
I have a custom table cell, and all I want to do is insert two button images inside it. This is my code:
gb = UIButton()
gb.setImage(UIImage(named: "skejt_zelena_polutka"), for: .normal)
gb.frame.size = CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 30.0)
            
rb = UIButton()
rb.setImage(UIImage(named: "skejt_crvena_polutka"), for: .normal)
rb.frame.size = CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 30.0)
            
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            
contentView.addSubview(gb)
contentView.addSubview(rb)
            
gb.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            
rb.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 140).isActive = true

But I am only getting the rb displayed, and not both. Also, rb is not margined from the left side of contentView by 140. I also tried restricting the leftAnchor of rb to the rightAnchor of rb:
rb.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gb.rightAnchor, constant: 140).isActive = true

with same result. I tried omitting the layoutMarginsGuide with same result. What am I missing here?

Adding the
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
gb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

solved the issue.
